# Adding in logic to E2E tests in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, logic, automated-tests, protractor, end-to-end

So my E2E tests are pretty standard. Our web app that we are building is basically a form.

My the tests that I have been building are pretty straight forward. The test that I ahve setup are as follows:

mainSpec: tests the homepage for specific elements that are present
createScheduledSpec: Navigates from homepage to Scheduled page and inputs all data into each appropriate element on the page, then saves the page and returns home and verifies on the ng-grid that it contains the proper item.

Now this is a very basic tests that I have created. It works fine and dandy, however it seems that if something like say a field requires a specific set of words(say, "goods" rather than "Goods" or "Good"), upon saving the user will get an error prompt stating X field is required/wrong.

How would I go about building logic into my tests so that if the example element is off, we fail the test rather than pass it(it currently passes cause the text was successfully inputted into the element, regardless if our webapp fails)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your example, it probably makes more sense to enter invalid data, then assert that the expected error message is displayed.

Comment: That actually makes more sense. Thanks again:)